# I can't figure out how to fix Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name

Tags: r

```
XXXTENTACION <- filter(Spotify, track_artist == "XXXTENTACION" & loudness) 
SuicideBoys <- filter(Spotify, track_artist == "$uicideBoy$" & loudness)

t.test(XXXTENTACION$track_popularity, SuicideBoys$track_popularity, paired = FALSE, alternative = "less")
```

```
lm.out <- lm((XXXTENTACION$track_popularity) ~ log(XXXTENTACION$loudness), data=Spotify, na.action=na.exclude)
summary(lm.out)
ggplot(data = Spotify, aes(y=track_popularity, x=loudness)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE) +
  xlab("Loudness") + 
  ylab("Track Popularity") + 
labs(title="Popularity vs Loudness of XXXTENTACION")
```

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(fitted(lm.out), residuals(lm.out), xlab="Fitted Values", ylab="Residuals") + 
abline(h=0)
hist(residuals(lm.out), xlab="Residuals", main="")
```

```
t.test(XXXTENTACION$track_popularity, SuicideBoys$track_popularity, conf.level = 0.99)$conf.int
```

```
(summary(XXXTENTACION$track_popularity, SuicideBoys$track_popularity))
lm2.out <- lm(loudness ~ loudness, data=data.frame(Spotify))
new.loudness <- data.frame(loudness = c(0.925))
(CI.energy <- predict(lm2.out, newdata = new.loudness, interval = "confidence", level = 0.95))
```

```
(PI.energy <- predict(lm2.out, newdata = new.loudness, interval = "prediction", level = 0.95))
```

[This is what I get when I try to run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9MMI.png)

[This is what I get when I try to knit the rmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfy7v.png)

Comment: In the 1st call to `lm`, remove `XXXTENTACION$` and set argument `data=XXXTENTACION`, not `Spotify`; 2) In the 2nd `lm` you are regressing `loudness ~ loudness`.

Comment: is this what you mean?

Comment: ```{r problem 2a}
lm.out <- lm((loudness) ~ log(loudness), data=XXXTENTACION, na.action=na.exclude)
summary(lm.out)
ggplot(data = Spotify, aes(y=track_popularity, x=loudness)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE) +
  xlab("Loudness") + 
  ylab("Track Popularity") + 
labs(title="Popularity vs Loudness of XXXTENTACION")
```

Comment: The 1st call should be `lm.out <- lm(track_popularity ~ log(loudness), data=XXXTENTACION, na.action=na.exclude)`. And `ggplot(data=XXXTENTACION, etc)`.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. In the order to enhance the chances of getting useful answers, it is a good practice to include all code, error messages, and data (`put() or `str()`) in the text (formated as code or citation), not as an image.